# operating function in another function

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to operate 50/50 player win/lose game based on random.sample([0,1],1).

```
def player_win():
    global player_win_count
    player_win_count += 1
    return player_win_count

def player_lose():
    global dealer_win_count
    dealer_win_count += 1
    return dealer_win_count

def game_draw():
    draw_game_count += 1
    return draw_game_count

def gameplay():
    i = 0
    while  i <= 300:
        test01 = random.sample([0,1],1)
        i += 1
        if test01 == 1:
            player_win()
        else:
            player_lose()
    print("player_win",player_win_count)
    print("dealer_win",dealer_win_count)
gameplay()
```

The 'random.sample' code works fine, but instead of expected result, it returns

```
    player_win 0
    dealer_win 301
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you mean ‘random.choice([0,1])’?

Comment: Are those global variables really necessary? Especially since you’re **also** returning the value...

Answer (score 1):

`random.sample` will return a *list* of the samples so `test01 == 1` is always `False`.
Example:

```
In [181]: random.sample([0, 1], 1)
Out[181]: [1]

In [182]: random.sample([0, 1], 1)
Out[182]: [0]

In [183]: random.sample([0, 1], 1)
Out[183]: [1]

In [184]: random.sample([0, 1], 1)
Out[184]: [0]
```

One solution is `test01[0] == 1`.
Alternatively, one could use `random.choices` instead and generate all the flips at once:

```
In [188]: wins = 0
     ...: losses = 0
     ...: for flip in random.choices([0, 1], k=20):
     ...:     if flip:
     ...:         wins += 1
     ...:     else:
     ...:         losses += 1

In [189]: print(wins, losses)
7 13
```

Answer (score 1):

As @salt-die has noted, `random.sample()` is designed to return a sample of the population and does so as a list.

To achieve the intended result, you could substitute `random.choice()` for `random.sample()`, which will return a single selection from the population:

```
def gameplay():
    i = 0
    while  i <= 300:
        test01 = random.choice([0,1])     # use random.choice()
        i += 1
        if test01 == 1:
            player_win()
        else:
            player_lose()
    print("player_win",player_win_count)
    print("dealer_win",dealer_win_count)
```

If for some reason, you are required to use `random.sample()`, then you can use the following modification to select the first element out of the list of sample results:

```
while  i <= 300:
        test01 = random.sample([0,1], 1)[0]    # use list indexing to get 
                                               # the zeroeth item from the list
```

Lastly, as a point of style:
It is sometimes considered Pythonic to simply test for truthiness/falsiness and thus this code could be refined a bit, if desired:

```
while  i <= 300:
        i += 1
        if random.choice([0, 1]):   # A `1` is considered equivalent to True
                                    # in Python, so we can skip setting the value
                                    # of test01 to being either 1 OR 0 and
                                    # simply return a 1 or 0 into the if statement.
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice in Python is to avoid `global` scopes so something like this is better if you really had to use a function.

```py
import random


def _counter(count: int):
    count += 1
    return count


def gameplay():
    draw_game_count = 0
    dealer_win_count = 0
    player_win_count = 0
    for i in range(300):
        test01 = random.randint(0, 2)
        if test01 == 0:
            draw_game_count = _counter(draw_game_count)
        elif test01 == 1:
            player_win_count = _counter(player_win_count)
        else:
            dealer_win_count = _counter(dealer_win_count)

    print("draw", draw_game_count)
    print("player_win", player_win_count)
    print("dealer_win", dealer_win_count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gameplay()
```

Otherwise you could simply do this:

```py
import random


def gameplay():
    draw_game_count = 0
    dealer_win_count = 0
    player_win_count = 0
    for i in range(300):
        test01 = random.randint(0, 2)
        if test01 == 0:
            draw_game_count += 1
        elif test01 == 1:
            player_win_count += 1
        else:
            dealer_win_count += 1

    print("draw", draw_game_count)
    print("player_win", player_win_count)
    print("dealer_win", dealer_win_count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gameplay()
```